# Sending a bot created txt file to a person or to a channel discord python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically the code that I have for my bot right now is creating a txt channel and saving it in the same folder as my atom edit file, the code looks something like this:

```
async def close(ctx):
    guild = client.get_guild(742566911778357330)
    rolename = 'Administrator'
    rolenamestaff = 'Staff'
    channel = ctx.channel
    channels = ('support')
    ticketLogs = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, id=745757663127797850)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=rolename)
    rolestaff = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=rolenamestaff)
    overwrites2 = {
guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages= False),
    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
 ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
 rolestaff : discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
 role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    if str(ctx.channel) in channels:{
        await ctx.send('You cannot use this command here.')
}

    else:


        filename = f"{ctx.channel.name}.txt"
        with open(filename, "w") as file:
            async for msg in ctx.channel.history(limit=None):
                file.write(f"{msg.created_at} - {msg.author.display_name}: {msg.clean_content}\n")

        area=ticketLogs
        await client.send_file(area, r"C:\Users\yoryo\Desktop\Fallback bot",filename=ctx.channel.name)

        await channel.edit(overwrites=overwrites2)
```

The problem I am having is that for some reason "bot" object has no attribute 'send_file'
Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was also thinking of using discord.File but I don't have any clue on how to include this, if you know how to implement discord.File in my code and make everything work, please post your answer, it would really help, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to send the file using [`discord.File`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20file#discord.File)

```
await ctx.send(file=discord.File("file.txt"))
```

or

```
await channel.send(file=discord.File("file.txt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

send_file doesn't exist, use channel.send instead like
`await channel.send(file=path)`